# Importing an external module in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use `axios` in my code,

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.get("http://someurl.com")
    .then(response => {

        console.log(response)

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error parsing data", error);
    });
```

This throws the following error :

```
import axios from 'axios';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try `import { axios } from 'axios'`. Does that work? Alternative: `import * as axios from 'axios'`.

Comment: @Mathyn neither works.

Comment: What version of node are you using?